# Angular Multiple Routing

Tags: angular, routes

I have a new design and old design for my angular application. the new design have some extra component and features. I would like to switch this application between the new and old UI. I'm planning to add auxiliary route, unfortunately it's not working. I want use the same path for my components. Do we have any alternate method to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you provide an example

Comment: @KurtHamilton 
 let's say I have a home page with name /url/home , assume this is old ui and I have updated this ui with new component and I want keep the path for this newly created component to /url/home its self. so that I can switch the Ui between old and new. So how to achieve this ?

Comment: So you want to be able to run the old and new components alongside each other, with *something* determining which one is to be displayed?

Comment: @KurtHamilton
not always, Assume I have 10 pages, I want change the UI only for 2 pages. then I will update only these 2 pages. So I will create new component for these two pages.
my plan is to keep one flag in the configuration file before compiling the code then I will change the flag value depends on the requirement.
important point is I want keep same url for new and old UI.
NOTE : I don't need two UI alongside , just want load only one UI for ng serve.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 lazy modules (A and B) at the root of your application, one for the old design and one for the new design and you define the routes inside each of them.

1 - Define your app-routing by passing this routes config :

```typescript
[
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./a/a.module').then(m => m.AModule)
  }
];
```

2 - Create a switch service that changes the routes on demand by settings the new routes like this :

Switch Service :

```typescript
class SwitchService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  switchRoutes() {
    this.router.resetConfig([
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./b/b.module').then(m => m.BModule)
      }
    ]);

    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url);
  }
}
```

3 - Do not forget to add the following configuration `{ onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' }` when you import your app-routing to reload when you switch and stay on the same url (`this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url)` in the `switchRoutes` method) :

```typescript
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })]
```

You can think a more complex switch service to toggle anytime you want

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's really helpful for me.
 Let me ask you this, Do we have any alternate method other than Module ?
Most of my components and service are been used by these two UI. 
I was thinking about multiple router like auxiliary , but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: I don't see another solution. Maybe there is.
When you use `router.resetConfig`, you have to declare your components in entryComponents array...
The idea behind lazy modules is that they add their routes configuration via `RouterModule.forChild`, so by switching via lazy modules you don't have to add your components in entryComponents array anymore